# How to migrate jaxb-gradle-plugin to newer version supported by Java 11

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Jaxb gradle plugin that generates code. How to migrate this code into new 5.1.0 version?

```
task jaxb {

    ext {
        packagePath = packageName.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
        destDir = new File(project.ext.generatedSrcDir, packagePath)
    }
    outputs.dir destDir
    project.ext.generatedSrcDir.deleteDir()
    project.ext.generatedSrcDir.mkdirs()
    ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.provided.asPath)


    doLast {
        project.ext.generatedSrcDir.mkdirs()
        ant.xjc(package: packageName, destdir: project.ext.generatedSrcDir){
            schema(dir:'src/main/resources/xsd/',includes:'*.xsd')
        }
    }
}
```